# Can't start video inside initState

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I tried to start video inside intiState , but didn't work, then I added it inside the `build` function and it worked, but now it cant be paused am wondering why :

Below is how I play the video :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller!.play();
    ....
}
```

then , when I try to trigger pause, it no longer pause , is it because of the build method, how best can this be achieved so that the state changes.

Answer (score 0):

this problem arises due to the fact that after pausing the video, your code runs again, and because you put `controller!.play();` in the build function, it plays it again after each build!
you can define one boolean parameter:
`bool isPlayed = false`

then use it in `didChangeDependencies` as follow:

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    if(!isPlayed){
       controller!.play();
       setState(() {isPlayed = true;});
    }
  }
```